# Update table if two columns exist in table and insert if one of the two columns are different

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table computer, which has the following columns:

`computer(computer_id(pk), office_id, computer_name, login, date, time)`

I am trying to create a mysql statement that will update a row if the `office_id` and the `computer_name` already exist and will insert a new row if it does not exist. I want to to still insert a new row if the `office_id` is different but the `computer_name` already exist and vise versa. If someone can give me some advice on it. I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mysql's `on duplicate key update` functionality to accomplish this.

Assuming you have a unique constraint on `(computer_name, office_id)`, the following query will insert a new row in the able for new pairs of `(computer_name, office_id)`, otherwise update the existing row:

```
insert into computer (office_id, computer_name, login, `date`, `time`) values
  (..., ..., ..., ..., ...)
on duplicate key update login = values(login), `date` = values(`date`);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here is how you specify which values to update
```

[see it in action here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9b4a/1)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding  UNIQUE office_id and computer_name to the Table.

an after that ....

```
//INSERT statement
    $stmt = "INSERT IGNORE INTO table";
    if ($conn->query($stmt) === false) {
        die("Database error:".$conn->error);
    }

// Check for success
    if (affected_rows == 0) {
      UPDATE TABLE
    } else {

 //Success and return new id
      INSERT IN TO TABLE
    }
```

Comment: @Chillin..  I just tried to help, you don't need give me downvote.